# C++ getline adding space at beginning of string

Tags: c++, fstream

This bit of code keeps throwing a space in front of the strings i'm attempting to retrieve.

```
void Texture_Manager::LoadSheet(std::string filename, std::string textfile)
{
std::ifstream infofile(textfile);

if (infofile.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(infofile, line ))
    {
        std::string texturename;
        sf::IntRect texture;

        texture.height = 32; //these will be dynamic based on what the text file defines as the pixel sizes
        texture.width = 32;
        if(line.find("<name>") != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::size_t pos1 = line.find("<name>") + 6; //Search for the name of the texture
            std::size_t pos2 = line.find(";", pos1);
            std::size_t namesize = pos1 - pos2;
            texturename = line.substr(pos1, namesize);
            std::cout << texturename << std::endl;


        }
    }
}
```

Here's the file i'm reading from. I'm trying to get the name and it keeps putting a space in front of desert and grass.

```
<collection>tilemapsheet;
<ratio>32;
<name>desert; <coords>x=0 y=0;
<name>grass; <coords>x=32 y=0;
```

Comment: If anyone has a better suggestion on how to do this as well i would appreciate any constructive criticism. I'm basically searching for a certain word then reading the information after it to set up textures in sfml

Comment: Are you sure the space isn't being output by a previous `cout` call? Also (unrelated), you should put `,pos1` at the end of your search for `";"` in case there is one before <name>

Comment: That's the first cout call in my code. thanks for the tip as well. it puts a space for both desert and grass. which it prints grass right after desert without leaving the while loop.

Comment: I had to swap `pos1 - pos2` to be `pos2 - pos1`, but apart from that it worked OK for me, with no spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since pos1 is < pos2, the result of pos1 - pos2 is a negative number. Since this is being stored in a variable of type size_t, which is an unsigned int, it becomes a huge positive number.
  substr is being called with a large number as 2nd parameter. In that case, the standard says "if the string is shorter, as many characters as possible are used". I think there is some ambiguity here and different implementations may lead to different behavior.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Let us print values of pos1 and pos2 to see what is happening.

```
        std::size_t pos0 = line.find("<name>");
        std::size_t pos1 = line.find("<name>") + 6; //Search texture
        std::size_t pos2 = line.find(";", pos1);
        std::size_t namesize = pos1 - pos2;

        std::cout << pos0 << ", " << pos1 << ", " << pos2 << ", " << namesize << std::endl;

        texturename = line.substr(pos1, namesize);
        std::cout << "texturename: " <<  texturename << std::endl;
```

In my case, I got the following values

```
0, 6, 12, 18446744073709551610
texturename: desert; <coords>x=0 y=0;
0, 6, 11, 18446744073709551611
texturename: grass; <coords>x=32 y=0;
```

When I tried with (pos2 - pos1), I got the normal expected behavior.

```
0, 6, 12, 6
texturename: desert
0, 6, 11, 5
texturename: grass
```

Comment: So i switched the pos1 and pos2 variables. Don't know how i messed that one up.... but for some reason now pos2 is becoming a very large positive number. I can't figure out why either

Comment: okay so it's because the find function that gives pos2 it's value is coming back as `std::string::npos` I'm not entirely sure why though.

Comment: ...... It's because i never saved the text file after i added in the semicolons. thanks for helping my stupid mistakes =P. would there be a better way of doing this at all?

Comment: Here is an explanation of what npos means.     http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/

Comment: To understand why a negative number turns into a large positive number, watch this lecture at UC Berkeley.      http://youtu.be/I0ngIuQSB6I